# 'System resource exceeded' when adding autonumber

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with ~400,000 rows.  I'm trying to add an autonumber field.  When I tried to add the field using the Design View, I got the error message:
`File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry.`

I don't want to make a permanent registry alteration, so I tried the following VBA:

```
Sub addAuto()

DAO.DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 1000000
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER Table large_data add column rowID AUTOINCREMENT", dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

This gave me the following error message:

`Run-time error '3035': System resource exceeded`

What should I do to add the autonumber field?

Comment: Have you tried opening the database in "Exclusive" mode? That might bypass whatever locking the database engine is (apparently) trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid that error by discarding the rows from `large_data` before you attempt to add the `rowID` field.  Then you must add the data back.

1. Make a copy of your db file.
2. Empty out `large_data` (`DELETE FROM large_data`)
3. Compact the db.
4. Add the autonumber field to the table's design.
5. Link to `large_table` in the db copy.
6. Run an "append query" to add the data from the linked table into the new version of `large_table`.

Something like ...

```sql
INSERT INTO large_table (
    fld1,
    fld2,
    fld3
    )
SELECT
    fld1,
    fld2,
    fld3
FROM linked_table;
```

Include the names of all the fields except the `rowID` field in that query.  The db engine will take care of the autonumber values.

Comment: I'll give this a try.  The table has 160 fields (i know, i know) so it seems I'll have to build the append query in VBA looping through the fields in a recordset of the table--or is there another way?

Comment: Why can't you use the query designer?  Doesn't it allow you to select 160 fields?